# ClosedXML export datatable with image

Tags: c#, winforms, closedxml

I am trying to export data from database to Excel using ClosedXML. There is an id picture in the datatable, I have only tried exporting data texts and I want to know how to include the of picture of the student to Excel.

```
public void ExportToExcel()
{
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Filter = "Excel files|*.xlsx";
        sfd.Title = "Save an Excel File";
        sfd.FileName = "Student List";

        cn.Open();

        cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT s.Lname, s.Fname, s.Mname, s.Gender, s.MobileNum, c.Course, s.Scholarship, s.EmailAddress, s.Address, s.District, s.ZipCode, s.Birthdate, " +
            "s.Birthplace, s.Citizenship, s.MotherName, s.MotherContact, s.FatherName, s.FatherContact, s.ZoomAcc, s.FbAcc, s.EducAtt, s.EmploymentStat, s.AssessmentResult, s.ProfilePic" +
            "FROM Student s INNER JOIN Course c ON s.CourseID = c.CourseID WHERE s.StudentID = @id", cn);
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", lblID);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cm);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        cn.Close();

        using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
        {
            var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "Student List");
            ws.Columns().AdjustToContents();

            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                sfd.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

                wb.SaveAs(sfd.FileName);
                this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                MyMessageBox.ShowMessage("Data successfully backed up!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
                wb.Dispose();
            }
        }
}
```

Does anyone know what and where to add the code for exporting image?

Comment: What type of data is the field s.ProfilePic? (BLOB, BASE64 string, URI string, ...)

Comment: @J.Salas it's an image datatype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Image SQL datatype is a little bit old fashioned, but will translate to byte[] in c#, so this o r a slightly modified code will do the trick

```
    using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
    {
        var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "Student List");
        ws.Columns().AdjustToContents();

        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            sfd.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            int numRow = 1;
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                    ws.Cell(numRow, 1).Value = (string)row["Lname"];
                    ws.Cell(numRow, 2).Value = (string)row["Fname"];
                    ws.Cell(numRow, 3).Value = (string)row["Mname"];
                    ws.Cell(numRow, 4).Value = (string)row["Gender"];
                    ws.Cell(numRow, 5).Value = (double)row["MobileNum"];
                    //[...] do with all the needed cells
                    var image = ws.AddPicture(new MemoryStream((byte[])row["ProfilePic"])) //the cast is only to be sure
                                        .MoveTo(ws.Cell(numRow, 7)) //Or the cell you want to bind the picture
                                        .Scale(0.5);
                    numRow++;
            }
            wb.SaveAs(sfd.FileName);
            this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            MyMessageBox.ShowMessage("Data successfully backed up!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            wb.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Actually,  you can Add a datatable simply adding it as worksheet

```
// Add a DataTable as a worksheet
wb.Worksheets.Add(dataTable);
```

but this **didn't work with Images**, so I used a for loop to do all work (and teach how to access Cell's Values)

Comment: How do I set the text cells?

Comment: https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Cell-Values

Comment: foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    var image = ws.AddPicture(new MemoryStream((byte[])ACTUALROWINLOOP["ProfilePic"])) //the cast is only to be sure
               .MoveTo(ws.Cell("B3")) //Or the cell you want to bind the picture
               .Scale(0.5);
} it's different from this?

Comment: I'm completing the answer with some example

Comment: I tried the code and I had an error in the da.Fill(dt), I tried removing the da.Fill but there is no data in Excel when I export it. It is totally blank. Am I missing something?

Comment: I get the "No mapping exists from object type" error everytime I run the code

Comment: I assumed the data retrieval was Ok, well as the DataTable column for IMAge is a little special (byte[]), I would define the dataDable before casting the readed data onto it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.datatype?view=net-6.0#examples